# How to listen to connection status change in Metro Style App?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am interested to know how to listen to a network connection status change.

For example, I would like to display a message dialog to notify my user that the network connection has changed from online to offline.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using javascript...

Link from MSDN: [Managing connection state changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700376.aspx)

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Corrected the link above, it was originally linking to a series of articles. It now links to the most relevant article in that series.